# How to use Webpack, typescript, and sequelize

Tags: typescript, webpack, sequelize.js

I edited my question beacuse I still have the same problem.

I'm using webpack, TypeScript and Sequelize. I'm trying to use Sequelize in a backend TypeScript file.

I installed Sequelize and Sequelize TypeScript by `npm`.

```
npm i sequelize 
npm i sequelize-typescript
```

Then, in my `server.ts` file, I test the connection like this:

```
import {Sequelize} from 'sequelize-typescript';

const sequelize =  new Sequelize({
        database: 'dbgala',
        dialect: 'mysql',
        username: 'root',
        password: ''
});

sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    });
```

When I build my app, I have an error in my node console: `"module mysql not found"`.

So I did `npm i mysql`

And now, I have lots of errors in my console:

[image]

This is my `webpack config` :

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./server/server.ts", // server.ts is the backend
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },

    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
          'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
'source-map-loader'.
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },
builds.
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },
};
```

I'm trying these solutions https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7509
and https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7509#issuecomment-335312273

I don't understand what is the problem. Does anyone have an idea? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your webpack config?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the `fs` issue by updating your webpack config with:

```
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  }
```

The `pg-hstore` issue is related to this `sequelize` [issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7509).  The workaround mentioned [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7509#issuecomment-335312273) seems to be the simplest. You can just add the following to your webpack config:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /Sequelize(\\|\/)/,
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')
    )
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi all, I also had this problem.
The solution was as follows:**

add in your webpack.config.js next

```
  externals: [
    'pg',
    { 'sqlite3':'commonjs sqlite3', },
    'tedious',
    'pg-hstore'
  ],
```